# Re-wiring a router into the main control panel

Tags: data-wiring, routers, internet

This is my first time asking so please excuse me for not being in the right place. Our home Internet was just upgraded to higher speed and so we got a new router that handles 5G and 2.4G.  I want to take our old router and wire it directly into my control panel to use the 2.4G system on an older laptop I use for online D&D.  I have no clue on where to wire it in to piggyback it and start to use it in a room in the basement with poor signal quality.  We have phone lines running throughout the house but only one room with an ethernet port. Any ideas?  Thanks all!

[image: Overall]
[image: Control Panel]
[image: Control Panel- Closeup]
[image: Router]

Comment: Re-wiring.  Stupid autocorrect!

Comment: Do you have an ethernet cable in the basement? Do you know where those blue cables go to? You should try to trace those cables and determine what they're for.....

Comment: don't post a correction in comments ... edit the post instead ... right now, it still says re-writing

Comment: 2.4G is WiFi ... ethernet is wired ... the two are completely separate .... which one are you asking about?

Comment: **What you want is doable, given enough expertise**. But reading your question and how you wrote  it, I get the impression that network engineering is not a familiar space to you.  It’ll help a lot to a) learn some basics about both network wiring and network (logical) topology, you don’t need to get into VLANs or anything but certainly grasp how NAT and subnets work.  Then when you have the vocabulary, ask for help on the Network Engineering stack.

Answer (score 1):

MoCA might be a solution for you (Media over Cable Alliance). I note that you have quite a few coax cables in your LV box, does one of them go to near the spot you want?  If so, you can get MoCA adapters to repurpose the coax for use with ethernet.   You'll have to do some research, but this should point you in the right direction.  Here is a place to start:  https://www.signalbooster.com/blogs/news/moca

Disclaimer:  I have no personal experience with it, but it seems pretty well represented out there, your mileage may vary.   Maybe others here can comment on experience with MoCA.

EDIT:  This may be a question better asked at another part of SE:  More to do with computers and networking.   You are going to have other configuration issues such as DHCP controls using a 2nd router.  Why keep it? Do you have enough ports on the new router? If so, just use the MoCA adapters (if your coax runs to a desired place) and plug it in. If not enough ports, just add a simple (non-intelligent) switch to add ports. Multiple routers can be a head ache if you aren't an expert, switches will often do the job.

Thoughts from other about migrating this question?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I know, KNOW, I'm going to get snipped for this by the moderators, but I couldn't resist.   Since you have plenty of phone lines, I suggest this acoustic coupler and a true dial phone.  I think they were good for up to about 300 baud, if I remember right. That's 300 bits per second for you millennials or .3KB per second or .0003MB second. It may slow your DD gaming down just a bit, but you could use your existing phone lines.

I know, I shouldn't post this, but it was just too much fun.

[image: acoustic coupler modem]

Comment: upvote for finding a picture with a dial phone ... also for giving me an idea for solving a low speed communication link problem between two arduinos

Comment: LOL, glad I could help.   The really sad part is I'm old enough and come from an IT background that I actually used that equipment!

Comment: you're off by a factor of 10 on the byte rate ... it's even worse ... lol ... i think that a good line could attain the blazing speed of 1200 baud, and then somebody would pick up the extension phone

Comment: LOL!!!! yes I saw that the upper practical limit was 1,200 baud, but it wasn't commonly used. And you're right....  .0003MB would be 3KB/sec. So the right answer is .00003MB/Sec.   That would def slow the OP's DD game down "just  a bit"! LOL

Comment: that technology is still useful these days ... dialup modems are still used for remote management of routers, etc. ... of course, the baud rate is much higher now

Comment: @jsotola  Yes, dial up is still a viable, if limited technology, but wired dial up is a long way from an acoustic coupler!    In college I would record BASIC programs on an audio cassette recorder using a magnetic pickup on the phone when I didn't have access to a TTY with a punched paper tape attachment.